# Why does a period get appended to my site's URL when I load the site in a browser?

Tags: google-app-engine, url, dns

When I navigate to my App Engine app (http://www.riabiz.com/) a period is sometimes (not always) appended after com, so if I enter http://www.riabiz.com/a/4153106 I get quickly redirected to http://www.riabiz.com./a/4153106/.

This appears to be causing a problem with asynchronous javascript requests to URLs that don't contain the period. I have no code within my webapp-based App Engine app that would do this as far as I know, but it is a relatively recent development (past coupe of months, and the app has been live for over a year).

I'm not even sure where to start, so any partial advice is welcome. Is it a DNS thing? AppEngine thing? My DNS host is BulkRegister.

**Edit:** I get this JavaScript error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.riabiz.com/rpc. Origin http://www.riabiz.com. is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Answer (score 1):

A dot at the end of a host or domain name indicates that the name is a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN), rather than a relative name. It removes any ambiguity during any DNS queries. It is perfectly legal and your application should be able to handle it.

Comment: I see. It looks like I get this error when trying to do XHR: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.riabiz.com/rpc. Origin http://www.riabiz.com. is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a DNS thing, not a problem though, read [this](http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html) document for more information.